# Group and Group content menu

Tags: navigation, group

I'm trying to display menu from Group page. All is ok with the module Group content menu.
But when I'm trying to display the same menu on a subpage of the Group, there is no menu as if the context is not passed and it don't know wich group menu to display.
Do you know how can I make this? Maybe with a view but I don't know wich field to diplay ?
I'm using Drupal 10.0.9
Thank you for your help I don't know where to look for a solution
Gary